# how to find an employee that has salaries with jpa hibernate

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have a method that returns an Employee by Id with a simple `entitymanager.find(id)` but now I need to find an employee by `id` that has a salary assigned to it, (the classes `Employee` and `Salary` are mapped through `OneToMany`), should I use an `entityManager.find()` or `entityManager.createQuery()`?

```java
@Override
public Optional<Employee> findById(Long emptNo) {
    try {
        return Optional.ofNullable(this.entityManager.find(Employee.class, emptNo));
    } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e) {
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

##### This is where i need help:

```java
@Override
public Optional<Employee> findByIdWithSalary(Long empNo) {
    this.entityManager.createQuery("select (e.empNo,s.salary,s.fromDate,s.toDate) as from employees e, salaries s where e.empNo=s.empNo");
    try {
        return Optional.ofNullable(this.entityManager.find(Employee.class, empNo));
    } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e) {
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

Comment: do you mean: an employee with salary > 0  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to change the query like below.

```
@Override
public Optional<Employee> findByIdWithSalary(Long empNo) {
    this.entityManager.createQuery("select * from employees e left join e.empNo=s.empNo where s.salary >0");
    try {
        return Optional.ofNullable(this.entityManager.find(Employee.class, empNo));
    } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e) {
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

if it does not working send your entity classes. we can do the same with that also.

Comment: The thing is i don't need to find the attribute salary i need to find the employee that has salaries assign to it meaning an employee has a salary assign to him then after a time that salary expires because a new salary is assign to him, the relation is OneToMany Unidirectional where in the class Employee i have a List<Salary>salaries

Comment: for this, you need to create a query coz you need to compare employee's last salary with the current salary.